# Configure Apache to record a host in access & error logs

Tags: linux, apache, httpd.conf

By default, `Apache` records an absolute URI in `access_log` and `error_log` file. Because I have multiple hosts (domains, subdomains) pointed to same directory and logs for all such hosts go into one access and error log file, I would like to configure *(if possible)* Apache to include host information within such log records. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Just put your access and error logs into your vhost config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in `LogFormat` `%{Host}i` or `%v`
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats